# Add Columns to Export CSV dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

I am reading values for employee table and exporting it to CSV like below:

```
ID | Name |     DOB   | Address | City | State 
1    Test   01/01/2000   xyz       ab     cd
```

Now My requirement is to add salary to this. I've salary in a list ready to be exported in CSV.

Output would be like:

```
ID | Name |     DOB   | Address | City | State | Jan,2015 | Feb, 2015 
1    Test   01/01/2000   xyz       ab     cd       1000        2000
```

Now the `month-wise salary` would be added every month with a new record. Like in April, March salary will be added.

How can I create columns dynamically on the basis of data fetched from salary?

Comment: Since, Salary comes monthy you can add 12 columns for every month and using switch case in code add salary to respective column. No need to create column dynamically. Or you have specific requirement to create dynamic column?

Comment: yes, I want to generate columns on the basis of data available in the database. Like now we've salaries of only 2 months in the database i.e. jan & feb, so no point in creating 12 columns.The report already has 40 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your output to `DataTable`.

And then try this

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(yourDataTable);
byte[] datatoexport = writer.ExportToBytes();
string fileName = string.Format("Export-{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm"));
return File(datatoexport, "text/csv", fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You need to identify from data, for how many months salary is coming. This can easily be done through c#. Then in the same logic you can use below code to add column to you excel sheet for each month.

```html
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("filename", other parameters)
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets.get_Item(SheetNumber);
Excel.Range rng = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
int colCount = rng.Columns.Count;
int rowCount = rng.Rows.Count;
rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, colCount];
Excel.Range newColumn = rng.EntireColumn;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, colCount + 1] = "Jan";
```

Hope this helps.